Unable to scrape TSP price data using Excel
I'm having difficulty scrapping share price history from the TSP website. When using the below VBA code, it doesn't pull back any data. I believe it has something to with not finding the correct HTML table to pull from, but I could be wrong. Can someone please look over the code and tell me what I'm missing? Thank you!
Sub FetchTSPSharePrices()
    Dim xhr As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim html As Object
    Dim table As Object
    Dim rows As Object
    Dim row As Object
    Dim cells As Object
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    ' URL of the page that contains the static HTML (doesn't require JS execution)
    url = "https://www.tsp.gov/share-price-history/"  ' The URL of the page
    
    ' Create XMLHttpRequest object
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Open GET request to fetch the raw HTML
    xhr.Open "GET", url, False
    
    ' Send the request
    xhr.send
    
    ' Check if the request was successful (HTTP status 200)
    If xhr.Status = 200 Then
        ' Get the response text (HTML content)
        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = xhr.responseText
        
        ' Debug: Print the raw HTML response
        Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML
        
        ' Now find the table by class name (assuming the table has class "dynamic-share-price-table")
        Set table = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors temporarily (in case the table is not found)
        'Set table = html.getElementsByClassName("dynamic-share-price-table")(0) ' Access first element in the collection
        Set table = html.getElementsById("dynamic-share-price-table")(0)
        
        'share-price-table
        'Set table = html.getElementsByClassName("share-price-table")(0)
        
        'dynamic-share-price
         'Set table = html.getElementsById("dynamic-share-price")(0)
         
        'fund-selection
        'Set table = html.getElementsById("fund-selection")(0)
        
        
        
        On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error ignoring
        
        ' If the table is found, loop through rows and cells
        If Not table Is Nothing Then
            Set rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            i = 1  ' Start row counter

            ' Loop through rows
            For Each row In rows
                Set cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td")
                If cells.Length > 0 Then ' Only process rows with actual cells
                    j = 1  ' Start column counter
                    ' Loop through cells in the row
                    For Each cell In cells
                        ' Print the cell content (e.g., "Row i Col j")
                        Debug.Print "Row " & i & " Col " & j & ": " & cell.innerText
                        j = j + 1
                    Next cell
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next row
        Else
            MsgBox "Table not found"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: " & xhr.Status & " - " & xhr.statusText
    End If

    ' Clean up
    Set xhr = Nothing
    Set html = Nothing
End Sub


This webpage is build dynamic and requires java-script. With a XMLHttpRequest, like you use, this is not possible to execute. So you may try to switch to selenium.

Oh okay, thank you for your explanation/response.
